# Prevent form submission but reflecting it in URL

Tags: javascript

Working with vanilla JS is there a "way" where i could essentially `event.preventDefault` while reflecting the URL on the form. I want to give people the choice to copy and paste the link and share to their friends.
My javascript code is doing something like

```
searchKeywordForm.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Clear all courseItems and start from scratch
    courseItems = [];
    courseContainerElement.innerHTML = "";
    let searchInput = document.getElementById("keywords");
    await fetchDataByKeywords(searchInput.value);
})
```

In so doing it's not reflected in the url that i can do `file:///C:/Users/bobby/Desktop/twitdemy/index.html?keywords=cas`
I have already did some checks for queryString so essentially it works.

Right now since there is `event.preventDefault` the url is basically static at `file:///C:/Users/bobby/Desktop/twitdemy/index.html`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.pushState()` to modify the current url without reloading page

```js
const searchKeywordForm = document.forms.keyform

searchKeywordForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const searchInput = document.getElementById("keywords"),
        newUrl =  `${searchKeywordForm.action}?key=${searchInput.value}`;
        
  history.pushState(null, null, newUrl)
  // log current location to see changes
  console.log(location.href)
})
```

```html
<form id="keyform" action="/formsubmiturl">
  <input id="keywords" value="foo" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```